# Is there an effective method to fill in correct inconsistent data using a second table when your data has a large size?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis, fuzzywuzzy

I have a table with inconsistent data which looks like this:

**Table 1:**

| flight_id | engine_number | aircraft_tail | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000_20180121 | 000000 | G-RHBZ | 2018 | 01 |
| 258741_20171021 | 258741 | H-RZBE | 2017 | 10 |
| _20150214 |  | V-RDER | 2015 | 02 |
| _20110287 | NO-NUMBER | G-EHRK | 2011 | 12 |

It's inconsistent because some fields do not respect a specified format. For example, the engine_number should not be equal to '000000' nor absent (row 2 and 3). I want to create another table (an indicator table) with the bad fields and the corresponding correct values, i have another table (which is massive) that i can use to create such indicator table

**Table 2:**

| engine_number | aircraft_tail | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 258741 | H-RZBE | 2017 | 10 |
| 348741 | V-RDER | 2015 | 02 |
| 348741 | V-RDER | 2015 | 03 |
| 589745 | G-RHBZ | 2018 | 01 |
| 587981 | G-EHRK | 2011 | 12 |

The indicator table i want to get looks like

**Table 3**: * The indicator table*

| bad_engine_number | aircraft_tail | year | month | good_engine_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000 | G-RHBZ | 2018 | 01 | 589745 |
|  | V-RDER | 2015 | 02 | 348741 |
| NO-NUMBER | G-EHRK | 2011 | 02 | 12 |

As you can notice both tables (table 1 and 2) have aircraft_tail,year and month columns in common. However i can't merge them to create the indicator table since i'm dealing with continuous data and the dimensions of my tables are huge. I tried to use the fuzzy wuzzy matching method to match between aircraft_tail,year and to fill in with the good engine_number but due again to data size it failed. Any ideas please to create such indicator table?.

I'm new to this field :)))
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could go with `merge`https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {"flight_id":"000000_20180121","engine_number":"000000",
     "aircraft_tail":"G-RHBZ","year":"2018","month":"01"},
    {"flight_id":"258741_20171021","engine_number":"258741",
     "aircraft_tail":"H-RZBE","year":"2017","month":"10"},
    {"flight_id":"_20150214","engine_number":"",
     "aircraft_tail":"V-RDER","year":"2015","month":"02"},
    {"flight_id":"_20110287","engine_number":"NO-NUMBER", 
     "aircraft_tail":"G-EHRK","year":"2011","month":"12"}]
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    {"engine_number":"258741","aircraft_tail":"H-RZBE","year":"2017","month":"10"},
    {"engine_number":"348741","aircraft_tail":"V-RDER","year":"2015","month":"02"},
    {"engine_number":"348741","aircraft_tail":"V-RDER","year":"2015","month":"03"},
    {"engine_number":"589745","aircraft_tail":"G-RHBZ","year":"2018","month":"01"},
    {"engine_number":"587981","aircraft_tail":"G-EHRK","year":"2011","month":"12"}]
    )

# Validator function
def bad_engine_number_detector(engine_number):

    lst_invalid_engine_number = ["000000", "NO-NUMBER"]

    is_bad_engine_number = False
    if engine_number == "":
        is_bad_engine_number = True
    elif engine_number in lst_invalid_engine_number:
        is_bad_engine_number = True

    return is_bad_engine_number
    
# Identify invalid entries on df1
mask = df1["engine_number"].apply(bad_engine_number_detector)

# Merge both tables (df1 filtered only with bad entries)
df1.loc[mask].merge(df2, 
                    on=["aircraft_tail","year","month"],
                    suffixes=["_bad","_good"])
```

| flight_id | engine_number_bad | aircraft_tail | year | month | engine_number_good |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000000_20180121 | 000000 | G-RHBZ | 2018 | 01 | 589745 |
| _20150214 |  | V-RDER | 2015 | 02 | 348741 |
| _20110287 | NO-NUMBER | G-EHRK | 2011 | 12 | 587981 |

Comment: Yes it works, i will test it for the whole data and check execution time performance. Thank you!